# Conway's Game of Life in Clojure: Add Glider to Grid

Tags: clojure, conways-game-of-life

I'm trying to implement the Game of Life in Clojure. I managed to implement the main logic, but now I'd like to provide a couple of functions that add an object (e.g. a Glider) to the grid.

Here are some functions  that work fine so far:

```clj
(ns glider.core
  (:gen-class))

(defn new-grid
  "Creates a 2d grid with rows*cols."
  [rows cols]
  (partition cols (take (* rows cols) (repeat false))))

(defn get-coordinates
  "Returns the row/col coordinates of each 2d grid field."
  [grid]
  (let [rows (count grid)
        cols (count (get grid 0))]
    (partition cols (for [r (range rows) c (range cols)] [r c]))))

(defn set-at
  "Sets the field at row/col to state."
  [grid row col state]
  (assoc grid row (assoc (get grid row) col state)))
```

1. `new-grid` creates a grid.
2. `get-coordinates` turns the grid with `true`/`false` states into a grid of row/col coordinates.
3. `set-at` sets a new state to the grid at row/col.

Now I'd like to add a glider. Here's my approach:

```clj
(defn add-glider
  "Adds a glider pattern to the lower-right quadrant of the grid."
  [grid]
  (let [rows (count grid)
        cols (count (get grid 0))
        row-offset (/ rows 2)
        col-offset (/ cols 2)
        glider [[false true false]
                [false false true]
                [true true true]]
        glider-coords (get-coordinates glider)
        grid-coords (map (fn [[r c]] [(+ r row-offset) (+ c col-offset)]) glider-coords)]
    (apply (fn [[r c]] (set-at grid r c true)) grid-coords)))
```

First, I compute `rows`/`cols`, and also the mid-point of the grid (`row-offset`/`col-offset`). Second, I build up a `glider` in a 3x3 field with `true`/`false` states. I turn the glider into coordinates (`glider-coords`), which I then move by the offset (`grid-coords`).

**Now I have a sequence of coordinates. I'd like to set the grid state to `true` on all these points.**

I wrote this program to test it:

```clj
(defn -main
  "Creates a grid and adds a glider to it."
  [& args]
  (let [grid (new-grid 8 8)
        grid-with-glider (add-glider grid)]
    (println grid)
    (println grid-with-glider)))
```

Which gives me the following error message when I run it using `lein`:

```
$ lein repl
glider.core=> (-main)
Execution error (ClassCastException) at glider.core/add-glider$fn (core.clj:32).
class clojure.lang.PersistentVector cannot be cast to class java.lang.Number (clojure.lang.PersistentVector is in unnamed module of loader 'app'; java.lang.Number is in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')
```

`Line 32` refers to the following code:

```clj
grid-coords (map (fn [[r c]] [(+ r row-offset) (+ c col-offset)]) glider-coords)
```

My questions:

1. What does that error message mean?
2. Is my approach using `apply` sensible, or how should one tackle such an issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error means that a Number is expected, but an array is provided. Why that happens, we can see if we capture the value of `glider-coords`, for example by doing the following while debugging:

```clj
defn add-glider
  "Adds a glider pattern to the lower-right quadrant of the grid."
  [grid]
  (let [rows (count grid)
        cols (count (get grid 0))
        row-offset (/ rows 2)
        col-offset (/ cols 2)
        glider [[false true false]
                [false false true]
                [true true true]]
        glider-coords (get-coordinates glider)
        _ (def glider-coords-debug glider-coords)
        grid-coords (map (fn [[r c]] [(+ r row-offset) (+ c col-offset)]) glider-coords)]
    (apply (fn [[r c]] (set-at grid r c true)) grid-coords)))
```

Now, if you look at the contents, you will see:

```clj
> glider-coords-debug
(
  ([0 0] [0 1] [0 2])
  ([1 0] [1 1] [1 2])
  ([2 0] [2 1] [2 2])
)
```

And doing a similar trick on the next, reveals the value of `r`:

```clj
(map (fn [[r c]] [(+ r row-offset) (+ c col-offset)]) glider-coords)
```

In the first iteration, the value of `r` is `[0 0]`, which is not a Number, as `+` expects, and that is the cause of the error message.

Regarding the `apply` there, it seems very wrong. I would rewrite that piece using [`reduce`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/reduce) + [`assoc-in`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/assoc-in), as the idea is to iteratively modify the state by traversing the results. You even don't have to destructure the coordinates vector. Something like

```
(reduce #(assoc-in %1 %2 true)
            grid
            grid-coords))
```

There's also an error with `get-coordinates`- you should return only those indices you want to update (= these, where `(get-in grid [r c])` is `true`).

Here is a fixed version:

```clj
(ns glider.core
  (:gen-class))

(defn new-grid
  "Creates a 2d grid with rows*cols."
  [rows cols]
  ;; makes sure its a vector of vectors, to get random access using assoc
  (mapv (fn [_] (into [] (repeat rows false)))
        (range cols))) 

(defn get-coordinates
  "Returns the row/col coordinates of each 2d grid field."
  [grid]
  (let [rows (count grid)
        cols (count (grid 0))]
    (for [r (range rows)
          c (range cols)
          :when (get-in grid [r c])]
      [r c])))

(defn add-glider
  "Adds a glider pattern to the lower-right quadrant of the grid."
  [grid]
  (let [rows (count grid)
        cols (count (grid 0))
        row-offset (/ rows 2)
        col-offset (/ cols 2)
        glider [[false true false]
                [false false true]
                [true true true]]
        grid-coords (->> (get-coordinates glider)
                         (map (fn [[r c]] [(+ r row-offset) (+ c col-offset)])))]
    (reduce #(assoc-in %1 %2 true)
            grid
            grid-coords)))

(defn -main
  "Creates a grid and adds a glider to it."
  [& args]
  (let [grid (new-grid 8 8)
        grid-with-glider (add-glider grid)]
    (println grid-with-glider)))
```

Comment: When you remove `partition` from `get-coordinates`, you'll get a non-nested sequence of coordinates, so you'll need only one `map` (and no `mapcat`) in `add-glider`.

Comment: Nice catch @MartinPůda! Feel free to edit that change as well :)

Comment: The combination of `reduce` and `assoc-in` is exactly what I needed! I had a very limited conception of reduce, i.e. I used it for producing sums of vectors and the like, but the notion of "iteratively modify the state by traversing the results" using `reduce` wasn't clear to me. Thank you very much!